# Increment Index and retaining index value to subIndex's in array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

Found a way to implement the incrementing value to index using regex.

But for subindex, how to retain the index value?

*Note: It helps, If there is a way to increment the subindex value.*

Sample Code: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3cL5jg2n/)

```
    let x = 0;
  let index = new RegExp("pindex", "g");
  let subIndex = new RegExp("psubindex", "g");
  let result = paragraph.replace(index, function(match) {
    return (++x);
  }).replace(subIndex, function (match) {
       return (x);
  })
```

Input:

```
const sampleParagraphs = 
`   pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        psubindex.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        psubindex.2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
`,
`.  pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`,
`   pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        psubindex.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        psubindex.2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        psubindex.3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
`,
`   pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        psubindex.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
`
```

Expected Output:

```
`   1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        2.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        2.2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
`,
`   3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`,
`   4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        4.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        4.2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        4.3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
`,
`   5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        5.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the referenced code is that it replaces all `pindex` first, then all `psubindex`, e.g. all `psubindex` will have the last index value 5.

You can use a single replace instead of two:

```js
function replaceIndex(paragraph) {
  let x = 0;
  return paragraph.replace(/(pindex|psubindex)/g, function(match) {
    if(match === 'pindex') {
      ++x;
    }
    return x;
  });
}

const paragraphSample = `
pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  psubindex.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  psubindex.2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit

pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.

pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.
  psubindex.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  psubindex.2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  psubindex.3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  psubindex.4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit

pindex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  psubindex.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
`;

const output = replaceIndex(paragraphSample);

console.log(output);
```